# how to use variable as field name in sql select

Tags: vb.net

i have combobox with this code

```
 headadaptor1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT code, fieldname FROM subject_1 ", cn)
    headcommand1 = New OleDbCommandBuilder(headadaptor1)
    headadaptor1.Fill(head1)
    TextBox6.Text = head1.Rows.Count
    'For i As Integer = 0 To head1.Rows.Count - 1
    '    Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(head1.Rows(i)(1))
    'Next

    ComboBox2.DataSource = head1
    ComboBox2.ValueMember = "code"
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "fieldname"
```

from another table1

i need to use select command from another table depend on combobox selected value

```
select combobox2.selectedvalue.tostring from table2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the item selected in your combobox to be used as column name in a different query that extracts data from a different table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the item selected in the combobox as the name of a column to retrieve from a second table you could write this code in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox

```
If combobox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim drv = CType(combobox.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    Dim cmdText = "SELECT " & drv.Row("fieldname").ToString & " FROM table2"
    Dim adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdText, cn)
    Dim table2 = new DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table2)
End If
```

Comment: error message
'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

Comment: Yes, sure the exact is `IsNot`